# Python sendall with variables and encode()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I must be doing this wrong.

```
s.sendall((str("mkd /" + folder.decode() + "/New Folder/ \r\n")).encode())
```

Is there a nicer way to write this?

Comment: Does sendall returns string?

Comment: yeah but python 3 demands a byte string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s.sendall(b"mkd '/" + folder + b"/New Folder/'\r\n")
```

Here's a more robust version that uses `shlex.quote()` from Python 3.3 (`pipes.quote()` on older Python versions):

```
cmd = "mkd {}".format(shlex.quote(posixpath.join(folder, "New Folder")))
s.sendall(cmd.encode() + b"\r\n") # send as utf-8
```

The latter assumes that `folder` is a Unicode string. If `folder` is a bytes object then you shouldn't use `folder.decode()` blindly because there is no guarantee that `folder` is encoded as utf-8. Whether `os.fsdecode()` could be used to decode it depends on where `folder` comes from.

Comment: Brilliant just add the the b in front of the second concatenated string. You are a champ!!